# Adding a button to footer in html

Tags: html

How to add a button to the bottom of a webpage? I tried this :

```
<div id="footer" style="text-align:center">
    <form id = "reset" action = "bug.html">
        <input type = "submit" value = "Reset"> 
    </form>
</div>
```

but not working ! I need the button to be static there itself (shouldn't move even if some other elements are added to the body afterwards). How to achieve this?

Comment: This is vague question, also as far as I see *Reset* as the value, you must be resetting the form, so you should use `type="reset"`

Comment: you means you want to fixed to a footer?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I have specified all the details in my question. Please answer to the question !! I asked about <div> not the <form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `position:fixed` like;

```
#footer {  
    position: fixed;  
    bottom: 0;  
    z-index: 100;  
}
```

Here is a demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/g8P8Y/1/** . See Reset button stickied at bottom